# how to call Strings in mainactivity.xml from Strings.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

1. I want to Call it in TextView

   ```
   <string name="Std_Name">Name:       Muhammad Abdullah</string>
   <string name="Std_Phone">Phone:     +923338157028</string>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the value from strings.xml to `TextView` in `mainactivity.xml` , add the following line of code to your xml

> `android:text="@string/Std_Name"`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
    android:text="@string/Std_Name" // Add this line to your textView
    android:textColor="@color/yellow_dark"
    android:textSize="@dimen/activity_text_size_small"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
```

Or, if you want to add text from `strings.xml` to textview from `MainActivity.java`, add the following code

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Std_Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

From within an XML layout, you can use the `@string/resourceName` syntax within the `text` string to reference a string resource:

```
android:text="@string/resourceName"
```

Using the `Std_Name` string resource from your example, that would look something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Std_Name" />
```

Official documentation for string resources can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource). You can also find a good example in the [Accessing resources from XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourcesFromXml) section of the [App resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String myName = getResources().getString(R.string.Std_Name);
String myPhone = getResources().getString(R.string.Std_Phone);

// Then do whatever you want with these values
```

Comment: how to use them in MainActivity.XML

Comment: first of all, pls explain how you want to use the values from strings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

**Call in your Textview text field**

```
android:text="@string/Std_Name"
```